# Pyinstaller exe not working when I change the icon

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, fatal-error, pyinstaller

I was making a GUI with python Tkinter. It also uses numpy and matplotlib also. So, I used pyinstaller and make a exe out of the python script. It runs flawlessly and did all what i wanted.
Then I tried to change the tk icon from the gui window (i am using windows 10) with this line

```
master.iconbitmap(default='image.ico')
```

other than this line i change nothing of the main program. Then using pyinstaller and I made the exe without any error. But when I tried to run the exe it shows "Fatal Error! file.exe returned -1"
What am i missing? How to fix this problem?

Also I have an additional problem, the 1st exe i build (without changing the icon) is running on Windows-10 and Windows-8 but not in Windows-7. In windows-7 it shows the same error "Fatal Error! file.exe returned -1"

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: Does the program work when you run it using `python` in the command line (without `pyinstaller`)?

Comment: off course, it exist and i can run that script directly and compile it with pyinstaller without any error

Comment: Have you bundled the files you need?

Comment: @Slayer has a good point, it's likely an issue with Pyinstaller not including your `image.ico` file

Comment: I didn't get it, how to include icon file?

Answer (score 3):

For those still experiencing this issue, I found that pointing the iconbitmap line to the full path will resolve the issue. I was originally having the same problem as the original poster until I entered the full path to my .ico file.

Example:

```
wm_iconbitmap('E:\icon_name.ico')
```

Comment: It worked OR for me to put the full path in the program.

Answer (score 1):

try setting datas like:

```
a.datas += [('C:\\Users\\KoushikNaskar\\Desktop\\Python\\image.ico', 'image.ico')]
```

from:
http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

datas is a list of tuples: (source, dest)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (most likely) is that you are not bundling the icon's image when using pyinstaller to compile your program to a .exe.

You'll see something like this in your .spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['your_script.py'],
         pathex=['your_path'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=['file_1_path', ....], # Here
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
```

Or you could do something like

```
a.datas += [item1, item2, ...]
```

Comment: well i learnt how to use edit spec file and add this line
a.datas += [('image.ico','C:\\Users\\KoushikNaskar\\Desktop\\Python\\image.ico','DATA')]
but it did not get the job done
then i found out if i keep the icon file in the same folder as the exe it works.