# Is there a way to convert a group of python files to exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of `.py` files and I want them to be converted to exe.

I know how to do that with a single `.py` script, but don't know how to convert multiple python files into a single application.

Also can we convert python scripts with js files also to `.exe`??

Actually I have 4 `.py` scripts with one `.js` script. They are all connected with each other to run. Is there a way out to convert them to `.exe`?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: How would they be run? Do you want them to all just start up? If so, using `threading` to import the files from a script called `main.py`, then compile `main.py`. You'll need to have some kind of mainloop.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729062/how-to-convert-multiple-python-files-to-exe) answer your question?

Comment: I don't know. I have 4 `.py` scripts with one `.js` script. They are all connected with each other to run. Is there a way out to convert them to `.exe`?

Comment: You can use a `setup.py` file to define the files you want to be compiled: http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install py installer.

   ```
   pip install PyInstaller
   ```
2. Execute the following command into your project directory.

   ```
   pyinstaller --onefile --add-data '<your .js file name here>.js:.' <your main python file name here>.py
   ```

   the above command will generate **dist** directory in that you will get your **exe**

Comment: I tried this with 2 .py (this two python file are interdependent) files and one .db file and it working for me